# How do I validate some hidden fields and not others?

Tags: jquery, unobtrusive-validation

I am using jQuery unobtrusive validation on a form. Some fields are hidden, and some of these hidden fields require validation and others do not. I understand in order to validate hidden fields I can do this:

```
var validator = $("form").data("validator");
validator.settings.ignore = "";
```

But this then validates all hidden fields. How do I specify which hidden fields should be validated?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add a class(like `validate`) to those hidden fields which has to be validated then

```
validator.settings.ignore = ":hidden:not(.validate)";
```

Answer (score 1):

Put a class on the fields to ignore, such as `validator-ignore`, then set that selector in the property:

```
validator.settings.ignore = ".validator-ignore";
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok. Here is what worked for me

```
$.validator.setDefaults({
            ignore: ":hidden:not(.validate)"
        });
```